# Merge two excel tables by checking difference in third row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two excel table like below and both are same but with different third row values .

Table 1

```
ID  Certificate No  Status
 1    2458            Done
 1    2459         
 2    2702            
 3   1852             
 3    8522            Done
```

Table 2

```
 ID  Certificate No  Status
 1    2458            
 1    2459           Closed
 2    2702            
 3    1852           Done
 3    8522
```

Final Result to show like this, the row number needs to same

```
 ID  Certificate No  Status
     1    2458           Done
     1    2459           Closed
     2    2702            
     3    1852           Done
     3    8522           Done
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you merging them based on Status? What if ID and/or Certificate are different?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio , they are same for all tables

Comment: "...but with different third row values", that means they are different. What will the difference be based on?

Comment: this is a list where users will fill their part and share with us

Comment: You say third row. Do you mean third column?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant third column and not third row, you could do something like this:

**Table1**

| ID | Certificate No | Status | merged Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2458 | Done | Done |
| 1 | 2459 |  | Closed |
| 2 | 2702 |  |  |
| 3 | 1852 |  | Done |
| 3 | 8522 | Done | Done |

**Table2**

| ID | Certificate No | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2458 |  |
| 1 | 2459 | Closed |
| 2 | 2702 |  |
| 3 | 1852 | Done |
| 3 | 8522 |  |

Formula used in the "merged Status" column in Table1:

```
=IF([@Status]="",INDEX(Table2[Status],MATCH([@ID]&[@[Certificate No]],Table2[ID]&Table2[Certificate No],0),1)&"",[@Status])
```

This is an **array formula!!** So you must press **ctrl+shift+enter** when you put it in your workbook. If you just press enter, it will not work.

Also please note that this formula will always "favor" the Status is Table1. So if the status for the specific ID and Certificate No is found in both Table1 and Table2, it will display what's in Table1.

You could also use this one:

```
=[@Status] & INDEX(Table2[Status],MATCH([@ID]&[@[Certificate No]],Table2[ID]&Table2[Certificate No],0),1)
```

This formula will just combine the statuses from both tables, so if for example it found a "Done" status in Table1 and "Closed" status in Table2, the "merged Status" would show as "DoneClosed". Just pick whichever behavior suits you better.